# How to change the directory .wine of Wine to a different directory

Tags: wine

I have Ubuntu installed on a rather small SSD. I want to be able to install Windows programs using Wine, but they have to be installed on the HDD.

By default, Wine creates a folder in the home directory `/home/<user>/.wine` where the installed Windows programs are saved. I want to change this to another location, such as `/media/HDD/.wine`

Is there any possibility to achieve this in a simple way?

Comment: You change it with the WINE_PREFIX variable

Comment: https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I looked in the "configure Wine" window, but to change the `C` directory is greyed out:

[image]

#### Simple solution: a link

What simply works however is:

- Move the folder `drive_c` from `~/.wine/` to any accesible location of your choice (The `c-drive` is probably what you really want to move, since applications are stored in that directory)
- Make a link from there into the folder `~/.wine/`:

  ```
    ln -s /path/to/the_other_location/drive_c ~/.wine
  ```

That should simply work (and it does on my system)

Comment: Does it still work if I move the folder on an NTFS drives? I mean, the file on an NTFS drive are all "777" by default; does it raise security concerns?

Comment: This doesn't work. In Wine c: still thinks it is in the original location and shows the available space of that file system.

Comment: I gave up on this. Instead I used Virtualbox and had it create the virtual hard disk on the MicroSD card. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [Can I store the virtual Windows installation somewhere other than ~/.wine? - FAQ- WineHQ Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Can_I_store_the_virtual_Windows_installation_somewhere_other_than_.7E.2F.wine.3F) as [Panther commented above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1594784).

1. Just enter this command, but replace "~/.wine-new" with directory you want:

   ```
   export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-new
   ```
2. Then you can use standard command for your custom wine prefix, e.g.:

   ```
   wine winecfg
   ```