# Do I have to uninstall wine each time uninstalling a program installed by wine?

Tags: wine, uninstall, evernote

Let me try to explain this.
Sorry for being a newbie.
Anyways, I have wine installed to install Evernote, then I realized Evernote version 5.9* is no good that I should go for an older version 5.8* which then I downloaded.

I used the `alt+F2` to open up the wine uninstaller to remote my Evernote 5.9* then I go into the `~/.wine` folder and deleted the `Evernote` folder within.

Then I tried installing Evernote 5.8* in terminal with wine which didn't work and so I tried going to the `add/remove of wine` to install which gives me the error message of

`Evernote was already installed by another user. Only one per-user installation is supported...........`

I searched up for this error alert, lots threads are saying to remove wine in order to remove things in the wine bottle.
Is this a must or else I won't be able to install Evernote again?

Comment: you do not need to uninstall wine. simple delete the wine folder - `rm -rf ~/.wine` and start over.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen ah alright! Now I get what it means, because by removing the whole `~/.wine` folder I keep on thinking it's also removing `wine` too! Omg really sorry for the misunderstanding when reading that thread.  I read it like few times before posting this question too.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen but let's say if I have more than one program installed by `wine` and I only want to reinstall one of the programs wouldn't delete the `.wine` folder have conflict the other programs too?

Comment: Depends, as with windows, not all applications uninstall cleanly. Personally I keep several .wine directories, depending on the complexity of the programs. You can specify which directory to run in or you can mv or copy .wine_program1 .wine

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/576888/how-to-change-the-directory-wine-of-wine-to-a-different-directory